# Ubuntu 15 Hotkeys Are Broken

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I have been searching around and not totally sure how to approach this issue with the Ubuntu Hotkeys. For example `CTRL+ALT+T`, my custom Hotkey `SUPER+E` for nautlius don't work. There are a few others. It worked when I first installed it.

I think there was something about `gnome-session-something` having to be restarted, but I couldn't run the exact file. I have these:

```
gnome-calculator             gnome-keyring                gnome-screensaver            gnome-system-log-pkexec
gnome-character-map          gnome-keyring-3              gnome-screensaver-command    gnome-system-monitor
gnome-contacts               gnome-keyring-daemon         gnome-screenshot             gnome-terminal
gnome-disk-image-mounter     gnome-language-selector      gnome-session                gnome-terminal.real
gnome-disks                  gnome-mahjongg               gnome-session-inhibit        gnome-terminal.wrapper
gnome-exe-thumbnailer        gnome-menus-blacklist        gnome-session-properties     gnome-text-editor
gnome-file-share-properties  gnome-mines                  gnome-session-quit           gnome-thumbnail-font
gnome-font-viewer            gnome-open                   gnome-sudoku                 gnome-www-browser
gnome-help                   gnome-power-statistics       gnome-system-log
```

Does anyone know how to fix the hotkeys? Is there some trick? It appeared there was a popular bug on the Ubuntu pages.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `alt+F2` the type 'r' and `enter`.  This re-starts `gnome-shell` in the least destructive way.

Then go to `System Settings` `keyboard` click on the `shortcuts` tab and verify that your shortcuts are there.  Any you have defined are in the `custom shortcuts` section.

If not there, set them up again, close system settings and try each of your shortcuts.

Comment: i will try this on my laptop soon, thank you. Its only on my laptop oddly. Thinkpad T550.

Comment: This didnt seem to do anything sadly. I am installing `gnome-shell` and going to attempt `gnome-shell --replace`